# How to keep changes made by Heroku to Discord Python app when adding changes?

Tags: python, git, heroku, discord

I have a discord.py app that I am now running on Heroku instead of my local machine.

It uses simple text files to track certain things, these changes to the files are recognised until I update the app and it rebuilds/restarts.

How do I ensure that the changes made by the app to the text files when I push new changes using `git push heroku master`?

Also is there a way to pull the changes made by the app to these files whilst it's running? Or at least view them?

I know a database might be an answer to this, but it's a route I'd rather not go down until I know for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know a database might be an answer to this, but it's a route I'd rather not go down until I know for sure

A database is definitely the right path here.

Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), without any kind of permanence. There is no good way to permanently save filesystem changes made on Heroku.

Generally speaking, application state doesn't belong in your repository anyway.

A relatively low-friction way to get started is to use [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), which has a free tier and in many cases works out of the box on Heroku. Just make sure you have a PostgreSQL driver listed in your dependencies and away you go.

If Heroku Postgres isn't automatically provisioned you can add manually it like any other addon, e.g. by running

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```